# How to populate Dynamics 365 lookups with text value from Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I am creating an Azure Logic app which takes data from an external source and populates Dynamics 365.

In the Dynamics 365 entity, I have 4 lookup fields which I need to populate. But from the external source, I am getting data in text format, which means I need to search value for lookup fields by text instead of Guid.

I am doing this by creating an Azure function but want to know if there is any possibility to achieve this with no code customisation? External data source can only send text as Dynamics 365 guids are not synced with source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly search using your logic app itself. There is an CDS connector step as "get Records", wherein you can filter query and match it based on your text criteria.

It can be you might get more than 1 record, ex: Account name: ABC company can be double in your crm.

you might want to narrow it down to fetch the desired result.

Once you get your Record you can use record and it's guid to fill your Lookup Field.

[Refrence to get Records](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/technicaldiscoveryforfinandops/posts/dynamics-365-for-operations-logic-app-how-to-get-one-record-if-you-do-not-know-the-unique-key)

[Here is latest Microsoft Doc for fetching record in logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-crmonline#add-filter-or-query)