# Locate the record ID or GUID for a lookup field within CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, crm, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

**Background:**

I have been working on this the past day and will appreciate any insight. I am creating a Logic App that automates the transfer of data from CosmosDB to CRM. My dilemma is that in creating my logic app, the fields are a 'lookup' field. I am unsure of where to find the guids for these lookup fields.

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

[image]

**Dilemma:**

I am trying to find the record ID or GUID for the 'Feature Category' lookup field. How exactly do I do this? I researched where someone mentions to search within CosmosDB,how would I do this?

There are other articles that state you have to List Records' within the Logic App? However, I am not fully understanding this.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate Dynamics 365 lookups with text value from Azure Logic App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61539420/how-to-populate-dynamics-365-lookups-with-text-value-from-azure-logic-app)

Comment: Thank you Arun, but not quite, as I need to locate the guid for the lookup field

Comment: to get the guid you have to query it using name

Comment: ok thank you Arun, and query this how and using what name? Query using feature category?

Comment: did you check the linked post and links there?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am a bit unsure. Would I query utilizing the Get Records within the CDS?

Comment: So I can use this query and the Common Data Service will return the actual GUID for this lookup field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your question and your comments, you need List Records in Power automate/ Logic apps.

Now when you use list records you can use filter query to restrict/get particular record.

For ex: Select empid,empname from employee where empname='XYZ'

Here is one of my Power automate/logic apps which list records from crm using some data from Sharepoint and getting crm record.

Now when you get the record in turn you get it's name,Id/GUID.

[image]